# Javascript validation for checkboxes in JQuery DataTable

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, validation

I have a table which is binding with JQuery datatable.

```
<table id="grid1">
 <thead>
   <tr>
     <th>Name</th>
     <th>View</th>
     <th>Modify</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Below is the javascript code for binding the table/grid-

```
function grid1_LoadData() {        
    grid1.fnDestroy();
    grid1.dataTable({
        "sScrollY": "200px",
        "bStateSave": true,
        'bDeferRender': true,
        'sAjaxSource': '/controller/GetData,
        'aoColumns': [
                     { 'mDataProp': 'Name' },
                     { 'mDataProp': 'View', "sWidth": "55%", sType: 'bool', bSearchable: false, bSortable: false, mData: 'View',
                         "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
                             return "<input class=\"enabledbool\" name=\"CanView" + full.ID + "\"  type=\"checkbox\" " + (data ? " checked=\"true\"" : "") + "/>";
                         }
                     },
                     { 'mDataProp': 'Modify', "sWidth": "65%", sType: 'bool', bSearchable: false, bSortable: false, mData: 'Modify', "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
                         //  console.log(data);
                         return "<input class=\"enabledbool\" name=\"CanModify" + full.ID + "\"  type=\"checkbox\" " + (data ? " checked=\"true\"" : "") + "/>";
                     }
                     },
                     ]
    });        
}
```

Before saving the grid/table data, I want to check at least `View` or `Modify` check box is checked. I need to write a javascript validation function.

This is what I have tried-

```
function Validate() {
    $(grid1.fnGetData()).each(function () {
        if ($(.checkbox).is(':checked')) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Waiting for the valuable suggestions.

**UPDATES**
I ended up using the below javascript function for checking validation -

```
function Validate() {
    var allOk = true;
    $(grid1).find("tbody tr").each(function (){
        var row = $(this);
        if (!row.Modify && !row.View) {
            allOk = false;
        }
    });
    return allOk; // Make `Validate` return true only if all rows validate.
}
```

What I was trying to do was if `Modify` and `View` are not checked then return `false`. When I checked with `$(gridProfiles.fnGetData()).each(function ()` instead of `$(grid1).find("tbody tr").each(function ()`, it was fine. But grid rows are added dynamically, last added rows won't listed when using `$(gridProfiles.fnGetData()).each(function ()`. Any solution?

Comment: At least a view or modify checkbox of each row I suppose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is worked fine for me -

```
function Validate() {
    var allOk = true;
    $(grid1).find("tbody tr").each(function () {
        var row = $(this);
        if (row.find($(':checkbox:not(:checked)')).length == 2) {
            allOk = false;
            return allOk;
        }
    });
    return allOk; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you should add a temporary var like oneIsSet = false and change the value if any one is checked.

```
function Validate() {
    var allValid = true;
    $(grid1).find("tbody tr").each(function () {
        var row = $(this);
        var thisOneValid = false;
        if (row.find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').size() > 0)
            thisOneValid = true;
        if (! thisOneValid)
            allValid = false;
    });
    return allValid;
}
```

Comment: can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: I'm on it but I'm supossing that you are checking more than one option

Comment: It returns false even if I have checked values.

Comment: `if (row.find($('.checkbox:checked')).size() > 0)` is false even if there is a checkbox is checked.

Answer (score 1):

Your function in my opinion is almost good. You made one bug in each function I would correct this function to:

```
function Validate() {
    $(grid1.fnGetData()).each(function () {
        if (this.is(':checkbox :checked')) {
            return true;
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

Main change is to move return false statement from each loop. In your version this loop would have always only one iteration. In my version it will iterate till find checked checkbox. If there is no checked checkbox return false. I have no compiler in my head so sorry for mistakes.

Comment: Im getting `Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'is'` in IE

Comment: replace this with $(this)

Comment: It returns false even if I have checked values

Comment: probably this selector $(this).is(':checkbox :checked') is wrong. As I said in answer I just only show you main mistake which was putting return false in each loop.

Comment: Try if($(this).is(':checkbox')){ if($(this).is(':checked')){ return true; } }

Answer (score 0):

Change your `class name` to **enabledbool** from **checkbox**

```
function Validate() {
    var flag=0;
    $(grid1.fnGetData()).each(function () {
        if ($(this).find('.enabledbool').is(':checked')) {
            flag++;
        }
    });
    return flag ? true : false;// return here
}
```

Comment: grid/table is binding dynamically. There may multiple rows. Your code is working fine for a single row. But when there is a row with checked values and other row with un-checked values, your code fails.

Comment: you have any solution?

Comment: @Sandy I used `flag` if there are `multiple rows` having `checked` or `un-checked values` then `flag` will be `incremented` then only it will return `true` if no checkbox is checked then `flag=0` and `function` will `return false`

Comment: `if ($(this).find('.enabledbool').is(':checked'))` is always `false` even there is checked `checkbox`